# Union and Intersection of Two Lists Without Explicit Recursion

Tags: list, haskell

I have two functions that are supposed to work on two lists.

```
unionB :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a] 

intersectB :: Eq a =>  [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

For `unionB` I have the following code that will take the union of two lists that does this without using explicit recursion.

```
 unionB :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
 unionB xs ys = [xs] ++ [[y] | y <- ys]
```

For `intersectB` I have the following code that will take the intersection of two lists (take min of counts). The only issue is that I am doing this with explicit recursion. Code is below:

```
intersectB :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
intersectB (x:xs) list
     | x `elem` list = x : intersectB xs list
     | otherwise = intersectB xs list
```

Is there any way to use the structure of my `intersectB` function, except without using explicit recursion? (i.e not mentioning `intersectB`  within its body?)

From my understanding, `intersectB` should be the opposite of what `unionB` does. I am assuming that `intersectB` would look extremely similar to what `unionB` looks like.

I can not use any imports. I understand that there is an import out there that does this already.

Thank you.

Comment: Um? List comprehension is recursion. (It's just syntactic sugar.) What's the big deal with avoiding "explicit recursion" vs implicit? (And as @Will's answer points out, your `unionB` is not a union: it produces a bag not a set, in general.)

Comment: @AntC the reason I mention `Bag` is the first version of the question mentioned `Bag`. I guess `B` in the functions' names is for "bag" too, so it's OK.

Comment: Thanks @Will, I wasn't criticising your answer so much as pointing out that the q is dodgy. For example, neither `unionB` nor `intersectB` are commutative in general. Debate rages about what should be the intersection of two bags.

Comment: @AntC thanks; my OK was more about the question -- it's OK "up to bag equality" I guess (compare this with the usual "up to isomorphism" in math... ). :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first function should be

```
 unionB :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]                                     
 unionB xs ys = xs ++ [y | y <- ys, not (elem y xs)]
```

And the second, of similar form,

```
 intersectB :: Eq a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]                                     
 intersectB xs ys = [y | y <- ys, elem y xs]
```

This assumes that `Bag a` is the same as `[a]`.